# how can I round of the grading system using C++

Tags: c++

Every student receives a grade in the inclusive range from  0 to 100.
Any grade less than 40 is a failing grade.
Sam is a professor at the university and likes to round each student's grade according to these rules:

If the difference between the grade and the next multiple of 5 is less than 3, round grade up to the next multiple of 5.
If the value of the grade is less than 38, no rounding occurs as the result will still be a failing grade.
Examples

Sample Input

4
73
67
38
33

Sample Output

75
67
40
33

here is the code I have made, can anyone tell me what is wrong in this, coz it just pass 11/12 test cases.

```
vector<int> gradingStudents(vector<int> grades) {
    for(int i=0;i<grades.size();i++)
    { 
        if((grades[i])<38)
            break;
        if((grades[i]%5) >= 3)
            grades[i]=grades[i]+ (5-(grades[i]%5))
    }
    return grades;
```

}

---

Here is the final working code:

```
vector<int> gradingStudents(vector<int> grades) {
    for(int i=0;i<grades.size();i++)
    { 
         if((grades[i])<38)
           continue;
        if((grades[i]%5) >= 3)
            grades[i]=grades[i]+ (5-(grades[i]%5))
    }
    return grades;
```

Comment: Better to avoid continue entirely, just factor the test into the next if statement.

Comment: Note that you don't need parentheses around `grades[i]%5` in either of the two places where that expression is used, nor around `5-grades[i]%5`. `if (grades[i] < 38) break; if (grades[i]%5 >= 3) grades[i]= grades[i]+5-grades[i]%5;` means exactly the same thing, without the (confusing (redundant parentheses)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You break out of your loop as soon as you found a grade below `38`, and don't even look at the rest of the grades.

You need to skip those elements by using `continue;`:

```
    if((grades[i])<38)
        continue;
```

Just noticed that you pass your `vector<int> grades` argument by value, so all changes you make to it in that function are not visible outside of it. You need to pass by reference:

```
vector<int> gradingStudents(vector<int>& grades) {
```

Incorporating john's advice, using more modern `range for loop` and eliminationg redundant return of the modified in-place passed in vector (that is, if you don't need to preserve the original):

```
void gradingStudents(vector<int>& grades) {
  for (auto& grade : grades)
  {
    if (grade > 37 && (grade % 5) >= 3)
      grade = grade + (5 - (grade % 5));
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> grades = { 73, 67, 38, 33 };
  gradingStudents(grades);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the result still remains the same. , it does not work

Comment: You will have to explain better. ***it does not work*** does not help anyone figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @kpsingh could it be because you are missing `;` at the end of `grades[i]=grades[i]+ (5-(grades[i]%5))`?

Comment: Since it returns the vector I don't see why changing the parameter is the fix.

Comment: The missing `;` would cause it to not compile: [https://ideone.com/X3rGyu](https://ideone.com/X3rGyu)

Comment: @drescherjm - you are correct; that fixed my code that I had to write to test this :)

Comment: @PeteBecker - agree; was trying to keep the original code to clearly indicate changes

Comment: @VladFeinstein -- my comment should have been addressed to the question. I've moved it.